# rc.local - script message suppression

Tags: linux, shell-script, raspberry-pi, nut, rc.local

I am working on a Raspberry Pi project; it includes NUT server configuration and making the OS Image read-only.

I have completed the required steps and configured the NUT server.

I uninstalled the cron and required a alternate method to launch my application script on start up.  after looking up some online resources, I have decided to use the `rc.local` file to launch my application script.

But when the system reboots I am seeing the my application script is continuously displaying the message generate by the NUT server command. Which used to be not visible when I was using the cron.

The following is the command that is generating a message every time the script is called. (My application script runs in a infinite loop).

Command:

```
upsc myups
```

Response:

> Init SSL without certificate database

I have tried dumping the script output to `/dev/null` but it did not help.

```
/etc/rc.local

printf "Launching Script \n"

/home/pi/dataLog.sh & > /dev/null  2>&1
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: I have my script at /home/pi/ directory.

Comment: I have tried the method shown in the link, still getting the message
Using following  -  /home/pi/dataLog.sh & > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @Christopher - I have used the /etc/home/pi/<script> but now I am getting error that file not found.

Comment: Yes, I have made it executable using chmod +x

Comment: My script is running fine, the only issue is that it is throwing message continuously,

Comment: `command > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Why the `&` before the `> /dev/null` ?

Comment: The script is running infinite loop, The ampersand allows the command to run in a separate process and continue booting with the process running.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Christopher for the answer. The right method is

```
/home/pi/script > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: @ Anthony Geoghegan There is 2 day wait time before I can accept my answer

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I don't ask many questions here but when I do I'm usually happy to wait a while for the best answer so I wasn't aware of this delay. BTW, I'd suggest that whenever you're writing shell scripts, it's always worth checking them with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thank you for the information, I was not aware about this tool.